# Learning to data between parent and child views in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, lifecycle

I have my parent view where I'm setting my `States` and I have two different views I'm trying to pass data between.  When subview_1 calls subview_2 I'm not getting the `binding data`, the compiler fails with the error, `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.`

My parent view I've set the states

```
@State var businessPhone = ""
@State var businessRating = 0.0
```

In subview_1 I have my bindings set and the data works fine.

```
struct subview_1: View {

    @Binding var businessRating: Double
    @Binding var businessPhone: String

    var body: some View {
    ....
    }
}
```

When I call subview_2 from subview_1 the data isn't getting passed as expected.

```
struct subview_1: View {

    @Binding var businessRating: Double
    @Binding var businessPhone: String

    var body: some View {
        subview_2(businessRating: $businessRating, businessPhone: $businessPhone)
    }
}
```

If I use `.constant()` with data that works as expected.

For `subview_2` I have the following bindings set

```
@Binding var businessRating: Double
@Binding var businessPhone: String
```

Comment: The error is telling something else. Please produce a minimal reproducible project without sensitive data and share the full code.

Comment: Ah you're right, thank you!

Comment: Your Views likely have `if else` statements or are very complex. Try breaking them down into simpler `Views` and change to a `switch` statement.